# Does an autoscaling group that contains spot instances respond to spot instance interruption notices?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm considering using spot instances in an auto-scaling group.  While I'm aware that I'll receive a 'Spot instance interruption notice' if my spot instances are going to get terminated, what is unclear from the documentation is if my auto-scaling group will spin up new on-demand instances to replace these when the notice occurs, or if they only get replaced on termination.  I'm aware that I could listen for these notices manually, but it seems like something that an auto-scaling group should be able to handle automatically.

I've tried testing this out on an existing auto-scaling group that had spot instances by changing the launch configurations 'spot price' to be lower than the current price.  This did not work as it would only effect new instances and not currently running ones.  I'm unsure of how to change an existing spot request's price.

What I'm hoping will happen is that on-demand instances will be spun up in the two minutes I have from the interruption notice till the time of termination.

Comment: It is best to ask their customer support directly :D

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-auto-scaling-groups-with-multiple-instance-types-purchase-options/

Answer (score 0):

If the `Launch Configuration` in your `Auto Scaling Group` is configured to use Spot instances then the new instance will indeed be a Spot instance.

The situation you describe is one of the challenges of using Spot instances; although the cost is very low, Spot instances can be terminated and the underlying resources used for a paying customer to fulfill an on-demand or `Reserved Instance` at anytime.

One way to avoid this is to use `Reserved Instances`. If you have a predictable long-term need for an instance, or are running a production workload, using Reserved instances is an effective way to lower your costs (albeit, not as low as a spot instance) without having to worry that you could lose your instance(s) at anytime.

Regarding changing the price, updates to pricing are applied to new instances only. After updating pricing simply terminate your existing instances and they’ll be replaced by your ASG with instances at the new price.